# Python file reading and printing, with exceptions and terminations

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I am a very new programmer who is self teaching Python. I have encountered a very interesting problem and need some help in creating a program for it. It goes like this

A hotel salesperson enters sales in a text file. Each line contains the following, separated by semicolons: The name of the client, the service sold (such as Dinner, Conference, Lodging, and so on), the amount of the sale, and the date of that event. Write a program that reads such a file and displays the total amount for each service category. Display an error if the file does not exist or the format is incorrect.

- Prompt  for  the  name  of  the  file  to  process  and  issue  an
   error message  and  terminate  if  that  file can’t  be  opened
- Verify  that  each  line  has  the  correct  number  of  items  and
     terminate  if  it  does  not
- Verify  that  the  dollar  amount  is  a  valid  floating-­‐point
        number  and  terminate  if  it  is  not
- Keep  a  list  with  the  categories  that  are  encountered  (they
           may  be  different  than  below)  and  another  list  with  the
           cumulative  dollar  amount  for  each  category.  These  are  two
           lists  but  the elements  in  one  relate  to  the  elements  in
           the  other  (by  position)
- Close  the  file  when  all  the  data  has  been  processed
- Display  the  categories  and  the  total  for  each  one

Our Sample text file looks something like this

```
Bob;Dinner;10.00;January 1, 2015
Tom;Dinner;14.00;January 2, 2015
Anne;Lodging;125.00;January 3, 2015
Jerry;Lodging;125.00;January 4, 2015
```

Here is what I am trying to do. I am trying to get an understanding of this and have some help from experts on Stack Overflow to solve this problem while learning. Thank you everyone!

```
import sys
def main():

    try:
        line = infile.readline()
        for line in infile:
            inputFileName = input("Input file name: ")
            infile = open(inputFileName, "r")
            fields = line.split(";")

            value = float(fields[1])

    except:
        print("Error: The file cannot be opened.")
        sys.exit(1)

infile.close()
main()
```

Comment: I haven't reached to an error state yet. At this point I am just looking for directions and help as to how to solve this problem. I have just started learning to read text files in python so I am not really sure how to properly approach the problem.

Comment: Then this question is too vague.

Comment: Well, thanks for stopping by and having a look.

Comment: Simple procedure: for each of the "do something or fail" parts, try giving your program input that falls under "fail", and see what happens

Comment: I was successful in having the error message displayed when I input an incorrect file name.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic sketch. This is untested so likely contains typos, logic errors and such. Also, it doesn't check all of the error conditions you mentioned. However, it should be enough to get your started. The main trick is to just [throw an exception](https://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/simple_stmts.html#raise) where you encounter an error, and [catch it](https://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/compound_stmts.html#except) where you can deal with it. That immediately stops processing the file as you wanted. The other trick is to keep a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/datastructures.html) mapping category to total so you can keep a running total by category.

```
def main():
    # Req 1.1: ask for a filename
    file_name = input("Input file name: ")
    try:
        # To keep things simple we do all the file processing
        # in a separate function. That lets us handle
        # any error in the file processing with a single
        # except block
        amount_by_category = process_file(file_name)
        # Req 6: display the categories - python will
        # display the contents of a data structure when we print() it
        print('Totals: ', amount_by_category)
    except Exception, e:
        # Reqs 1-3: display errors
        print('Error processing file:', e)

def process_file(file_name):
        # Req 1.2: open the file
        infile = open(file_name, 'r')
        # Req 4.1: somewhere to remember the categories
        amount_by_catgeory = {}
        # Reqs 2-4: we are dealing with a many line file
        # Req 5: when we reach the end, python closes the file for us automatically
        for line in infile:
            # Req 2.1: each line should have 4 values separated by ;
            fields = line.split(';')
            # Req 2.2: does this line have 4 values?
            if len(fields) != 4:
                raise Exception('Expected 4 fields but found %s' % len(fields))
            # Req 3: is the third value a number?
            value = float(fields[2])
            # Req 4.2: what category does this line belong to?
            category = fields[1]
            # Req 4.3.1: have we seen this category before?
            if not category in amount_by_category:
                # Req 4.3.2: accumulations start from 0?
                amount_by_category[category] = 0.0f
            # Req 4.4: increase the cumulative amount for the category
            amount_by_category[category] += value

        return amount_by_category
```

Comment: How would the output be printed?

Comment: It's printed by this line: `print('Totals: ', amount_by_category)`. That'll be kind of ugly, but readable. If you want something nicer you'll have to write a bit more code. Maybe something like `for category, value in amount_by_category.items(): print('Value for %s is %s' % (category, value))`

Comment: Can you please add that to your code so its more workable? I really learn better when its a working program. The file reading in Python is very new to me.

Comment: @CainBoozer I hope there's more than enough there to get you started. If you want to tweak the program to improve formatting, etc. feel free to do so. As the purpose of this site is really to answer targeted questions, not produce a full working program for somebody I'm going to leave things here. If you found this answer helpful marking it correct and/or up-voting it would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks for your input. I would up vote but my reputation is low to do so.

Comment: @CainBoozer I fixed the typo. there was a missing comma in Exception catch part