# Reading a text file in Python and choosing categories from it

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, exception, recursion

Hello I am a very new programmer who is self teaching Python. I have encountered a very interesting problem and need some help in creating a program for it. It goes like this

A hotel salesperson enters sales in a text file. Each line contains the following, separated by semicolons: The name of the client, the service sold (such as Dinner, Conference, Lodging, and so on), the amount of the sale, and the date of that event. Write a program that reads such a file and displays the total amount for each service category. Display an error if the file does not exist or the format is incorrect.

- Prompt for the name of the file to process and issue an
  error message and terminate if that file can’t be opened
- Verify that each line has the correct number of items and
    terminate if it does not
- Verify that the dollar amount is a valid floating-­‐point
       number and terminate if it is not
- Keep a list with the categories that are encountered (they
          may be different than below) and  another list with the
          cumulative dollar amount for each category. These are two
          lists but the elements in one relate to the elements in
          the other (by position)
- Close the file when all the data has been processed
- Display the categories and the total for each one

Our Sample text file looks something like this

```
Bob;Dinner;10.00;January 1, 2015
Tom;Dinner;14.00;January 2, 2015
Anne;Lodging;125.00;January 3, 2015
Jerry;Lodging;125.00;January 4, 2015
```

Here is my code. I am getting indentation error at `main()`. Can someone please help in correcting my code and perfecting it as per the question? Please feel free to tear down the entire code if needed.

```
import sys
def main():

    try:
        line = infile.readline()
        for line in infile:
            inputFileName = input("Input file name: ")
            infile = open(inputFileName, "r")
            fields = line.split(";")

            value = float(fields[1])

    except:
        print("Error: The file cannot be opened.")
        sys.exit(1)

    def process_file(file_name):
        infile = open(file_name, 'r')
        # a dictionary mapping category to total amount for that category
        amount_by_category = {}
        try:
            line = infile.readline()
            for line in infile:
                fields = line.split(';')
                if len(fields) != 4:
                    raise Exception('Expected 4 fields but found %s' % len(fields))
                value = float(fields[2])
                category = fields[1]
                if not category in amount_by_category:
                    amount_by_category[category] = 0.0
                amount_by_category[category] += value
            return amount_by_category
main()
```

Output from running with the above correct file should be:

```
Enter the name of the file to display: input.txt

Totals:
Dinner: $  24.00

Lodging: $ 250.00
```

Comment: Simply drop the `f` from `0.0f`; `float` values simply are numbers that contain a single decimal separator `.` (i.e. `0.0` or `0.` or `.0`).

Comment: amount_by_catgory should be amount_by_category

Comment: Thank you. I edited it and now I am getting an error at main()

Comment: This exact question was posted and deleted a few hours ago by a user whose account had your exact same name (which you have now changed). Please don't post the same question from multiple accounts.

Comment: Because you are missing an except. Look at your method. You opened a try but never closed it.

Comment: Your code contains trivial typos: category, catgeory, catgory ... Try do fix it first.

Comment: Sorry for that. I just fixed them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python file reading and printing, with exceptions and terminations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113860/python-file-reading-and-printing-with-exceptions-and-terminations)

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have spent some considerable amount of time, but I think it's always best to use the tools at hand.

For sake of efficiency, and I understand that it's not 100% what you're looking for as you're learning, but importing the data into `pandas` is a great time saver.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header = None, sep=';')

dinner = df[df[1]=='Dinner'][2].sum() #1 is the "Dinner/Lodge" and 2 is "Cost"

print(dinner)

>>> 24.0
```

Just to keep it in mind, while you can do anything without the use of additional packages, they're there for a reason and having the right tool makes the job easier. *Assuming it's not a homework problem*

Comment: I truly appreciate your help, but at this point in our course, we are not allowed to import pandas. We are in a beginner level course.

Answer (score 1):

With a text file containing:

```
Bob;Dinner;10.00;January 1, 2015
Tom;Dinner;14.00;January 2, 2015
Anne;Lodging;125.00;January 3, 2015
Jerry;Lodging;125.00;January 4, 2015
```

I made some minimal changes and got the output you're looking for:

```
Totals:
Dinner: $ 24.0
Lodging: $ 250.0
```

There was tons of issues I ran into with the original code. `amount_by_category` was spelled wrongly. `try` in `process_file` needed an `except`. When reading the file, it was actually skipping the first line, so `Bob` was never being processed. That's because you read a line, then did nothing with it and went into a loop. `0.0f` is not a float, just doing `0.0` will cast it properly.

You should also consider to stop using `try` `except` as a crutch. It's a very lazy way to program instead of actually fixing the errors. In this case, you can easily check the file if the inputs are what you need, so the use of `try` is unnecessary.

```
def main():
    file_name = input("Input file name: ")
    amount_by_category = process_file(file_name)
    if amount_by_category:
        print 'Totals:'
        for key in amount_by_category:
            print '{0}: $ {1}'.format(key, amount_by_category.get(key) )

def process_file(file_name):
    infile = open(file_name, 'r')
    # a dictionary mapping category to total amount for that category
    amount_by_category = {}
    for line in infile:
        fields = line.split(';')
        if len(fields) != 4:
            raise Exception('Expected 4 fields but found %s' % len(fields))
        value = float(fields[2])
        category = fields[1]
        if not category in amount_by_category:
            amount_by_category[category] = 0.0
        amount_by_category[category] += value
    return amount_by_category

main()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I just ran the code and it is giving the output but it is reversed. How to we turn it as per the expected/required output?

Comment: What do you mean? What's the output it's giving you now?

Comment: It is giving Lodging before Dinner, while it should print dinner before lodging as per the original output required in the question.

Comment: A `dictionary` has no order so it may be better to use an `OrderedDict` instead to get the same ouput it reads from. Or the `keys` of the `dictionary` could just be sorted prior if it needs to be alphabetically.

Comment: OP never mentioned output needs to be a specific order so doesn't seem to be a "requirement". Also, OP looks like he deleted his account so I guess this doesn't matter :)

Comment: How would we use it in you code? I cant see any dataDict method in your code?

Comment: Well I shouldn't say requirement, but I'd like to learn a method where it prints just like the output, in that order.

Comment: OrderedDict: https://pymotw.com/2/collections/ordereddict.html
Its usage is very similar to the built-in dict. This is getting off topic so if you're taking this as a learning opportunity then give it a try, and open a new thread if you're stumped.

Comment: Start your own question and I'll be happy to help. (might be better to break it down to your specific problem anyways)

Comment: I couldn't post on this account but I have used my other account to post t. Here it is

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139524/reading-a-text-file-n-python

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a syntax error since you cannot use the letter 'f' after your number.
In python you can get a floating number wither by using the decimal point or by using the built-in type `float()`

float(0) = 0.0
0. = 0.0
0.0 = 0.0

All will yield the same result

Comment: wrong formatting. 
float(0) = 0.0
0. = 0.0
0.0 = 0.0

sorry for the formatting in my answer

Comment: Sorry for that. I just fixed it. I am getting an indentation error at main()

Comment: sometimes depending on your text editor and tabs this can happen. according to python PEP8 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces), spaces are the preferred choice for indentation. make sure your text editor is indenting using spaces

Comment: Well this is the .txt file we are using

Bob;Dinner;10.00;January 1, 2015

Tom;Dinner;14.00;January 2, 2015

Anne;Lodging;125.00;January 3, 2015

Jerry;Lodging;125.00;January 4, 2015

Comment: By the way I see you define process_file function inside main() but not calling it anywhere in your code sample

Comment: I meant your text editor and not the text file. What text editor/ide are you using to write the code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are looking for specific python3.x answers or not, but I copy pasted your code and did some minor alterations.
For 3.1, **raw_input** should be changed to **input**.
I hope it helps.

```
import os

def process_file(file_name):
    infile = open(file_name, 'r')
    amount_by_category = {}
    # a dictionary mapping category to total amount for that category

    line = infile.readline()
    for line in infile:
        fields = line.split(';')
        if len(fields) != 4:
            raise Exception('Expected 4 fields but found %s' % len(fields))
        value = float(fields[2])
        category = fields[1]
        if category not in amount_by_category:
            amount_by_category[category] = 0.0
        amount_by_category[category] += value

    return amount_by_category


if __name__== "__main__": 
    filePath = raw_input("Input file name: ")
    if not os.path.exists(filePath):
        raise Exception("File Does not exists: "+filePath)
    dataDict = process_file(filePath)
    for key,value in dataDict.iteritems():
        print key,value
```